# What could be an UML "model diagram"?

Tags: spring-boot, uml

I have a **task**:

Implement a spring boot REST service that models the structure of a university and provides a class schedule for a specific student on a specific day. A schedule is a list of lectures that a student has on a specific day, time and order not to be taken into account.

And one of the **requirements**:

Provide UML diagram of university as well as model diagram in app.

Could you tell me what is meant by a model diagram? I rummaged through many articles and did not see a word about the model diagram. I have two guesses what is meant: database model (relationships between databases) or class diagram.

Comment: Ask them, not us. This is not a common term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to see the ERD or Entity Relationship Diagram

Comment: Yes, maybe it's database model what they meant. But that would be just guessing.